# Strip languagecode from URL and save as environment variable via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to strip a language code from an URL and save this code so it can be accessed in PHP, either via the $_SERVER variable or $_GET. The site URL is as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/dir%20ectory/dynamic/url/
http://www.example.com/dir%20ectory/EN/dynamic/url/
```

Whereas the directory name is stored as environmental variable in htaccess, in "PATH".

```
# Set PATH variable
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:/dir\ ectory]

# Using belows method, remove the Language code, and save it to LANG
RewriteRule ^%{ENV:PATH}/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)$ %{ENV:PATH}/$2 [E=LANG:$1]

# Do some more stuff, all working fine (even w/o the above rewrite)
#....

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:PATH}/index.php?path=$1&lang=%{ENV:LANG} [L]
```

The rewriterule of line 5 logically saves the language code to %{ENV:LANG}, though the $_GET value for lang is empty. Besides, images (and other static content) requested via:

```
http://www.example.com/dir%20ectory/EN/static/img.png
```

do not show on the page, meaning the image URL is handled by line 12, not line 10 (which makes sense because I use %{REQUEST_FILENAME}, which is not rewritten). I would like to know what I'm doing wrong with %{ENV:LANG} and how the language code can be removed from %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.

update: the language was stored, but not for URL's ending with the language code. edited (.+) for (.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using information from Jon Lin, I came up with the following solution after a couple of days fixing problems.

```
# Set PATH variable
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:/dir\ ectory]

# Using belows method, remove the Language code, and save it to LANG
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})(|/|/(.*))$ $3 [E=LANG:$1]

# Do some more stuff, all working fine (even w/o the above rewrite)
#....

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:PATH}/index.php?path=$1&lang=%{ENV:LANG} [L]
```

This will support paths like: /EN | /EN/ | /EN/dynamic/path.

Note that the directory is not in the RewriteRule, this is because it also isn't in the string. (e.g. see value for $_GET['path']). Also note that the rewriterule (line 4) rewrites the match to $3 and not to $2. This is because $2 may also start with a /, whereas $3 is the result of (.*) and thus has not starting /. A starting / causes "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" to change.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the condition nor the `SetEnvIf` (which is a completely different module and doesn't interact with rerwite directives). You just need:

```
# Set PATH variable, not sure if this is the correct way but it works...
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:/dir\ ectory]

RewriteRule ^%{ENV:PATH}/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.+)$ %{ENV:PATH}/$2 [L,E=LANG:$1]
```

The `E` flag allows you to set an environment variable, in this case `LANG` and it sets it to the value captured by the first group, `([a-zA-Z]{2})`

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. Yet I face another problem "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" does still not work, for that variable is (I believe) not rewritten with the above line. How to make sure www.example.com/dir%20ectory/GB/static/img.png goes to www.example.com/dir%20ectory/static/img.png ?

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't know where this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is coming from

Comment: excuses for that, I edited the question a bit to elaborate the problem.